# Facing compiler error while trying to implement minimalist architecture using ValueNotifier and ValueListenable

Tags: flutter

I am trying to learn Flutter minimalist architecture from [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-state-management-for-minimalists-4c71a2f2f0c1). I implemented a repository extending the `ValueNotifier` of type `List<Shops>` like below. It will initially return an empty list of `Shop`. I will be getting the `shopList` from server, so for which I introduced Delay for now and return the actual shop list after 3 seconds.

```dart
class ShopRepository extends ValueNotifier<List<Shops>> {
  final List<Shops> shopList = [];

  ShopRepository() : super(getInitalShopList([]));

  void repositoryInitialize() {
    getActualShopList();
  }

  static List<Shops> getInitalShopList(List<Shops> argShopList) {
    return argShopList;
  }

  void getActualShopList() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3))
        .then((onValue) => getInitalShopList(shopList));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

I wrote a service layer for this for this repository where I initialize it:

```
import 'package:test_app/repository/shops_repository.dart';

class ShopService{
  final shopRepository = ShopRepository();

  void serviceInitializer(){
    shopRepository.repositoryInitialize();
  }

  void dispose() {
    shopRepository.dispose();
  }

}
```

In the UI layer I am using the `ValueListenableBuilder` as below,

```
import 'package:test_app/service_locator.dart';
import 'package:test_app/services/shop_service';

class ShopPageList extends StatelessWidget {
  const ShopPageList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final shopService = getIt<ShopService>();
    return ValueListenableBuilder<List<Shops>>(
        valueListenable: shopService.shopRepository,
        builder: (context, shopList, child) {
          print(shopList);
          return Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: shopCardList,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

At line `valueListenable: shopService.shopRepository` I am getting the compiler error as

> The argument type 'ShopRepository' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ValueListenable<List>'.

But the class `ShopRepository` extending `ValueNotifier<List<Shops>>`. I have tried restarting the Android Studio but it didn't work.

I have setup the `GetIt` instance as below

```
final getIt = GetIt.instance;
void setUpGetIt(){
  getIt.registerLazySingleton<ShopService>(() => ShopService());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start by adding a diagram from my [Flutter state management for minimalists](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-state-management-for-minimalists-4c71a2f2f0c1?sk=6f9cedfb550ca9cc7f88317e2e7055a0) article that you linked to:

[image]

Value notifiers belong in the state management layer because the UI listens to them for updates.

Repositories, on the other hand, are sources of data. They are another common name for services and thus belong in the service layer. The state management layer goes between the UI layer and the service layer. That means the UI layer shouldn't know anything about an app services (i.e., repositories). Also the service layer shouldn't know anything about the state management layer.

## Some notes about your code

#### Renaming your "repository"

Your `ShopRepository` is a value notifier, not really the repository itself so let's call it `ShopNotifier` to make that clear.

### UI layer

Your UI layer shouldn't know anything about the service layer. It only knows about the state management layer.

Let's refactor the UI like so:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final myNotifier = getIt<ShopNotifier>();
  return ValueListenableBuilder<List<Shop>>(
    valueListenable: myNotifier,
    builder: (context, shopList, child) {
      return Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(children: shopCardList),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Note:

- You use GetIt to get a reference to your state management layer, which in this case is just the single `ShopNotifier` value notifier. If you have several value notifiers that the UI is listening to, then you can optionally group them into a single file. (That's what I did in my tutorial.) In that case you would get a reference to the notifier as `myStateManager.myNotifier`.

Since you are using GetIt to get a reference to your state manager then you need to register it:

```dart
void setUpGetIt() {
  getIt.registerLazySingleton<ShopNotifier>(() => ShopNotifier());
}
```

#### State management layer

The job of the state management layer is to receive events from the UI and translate them into new state. Where does the state management layer get the new state from? Usually from a service (aka data repository).

Here is how I would refactor your state management class:

```dart
class ShopNotifier extends ValueNotifier<List<Shop>> {
  ShopNotifier() : super(_initialShopList);

  static const List<Shop> _initialShopList = [];

  Future<void> init() async {
    final shopService = getIt<ShopService>();
    value = await shopService.getShopList();
  }
}
```

Notes:

- You initialized the value notifier with an empty list by passing `[]` into the `super` constructor. That's all you need to do there. No need to call other methods.
- I also defined an `init()` method that updates the `value` (list of shops) for the `ValueNotifier`. You would call this from the `initState()` method of a `StatefulWidget` in the UI layer. That way the `init()` method would get called once when the UI first loads.

  ```
  // class _ShopPageListState
  @override
  void initState() {
    getIt<ShopNotifier>().init();
    super.initState();
  }
  ```
- The state management layer gets it data from services so that's what the call to `getShopList()` is for.

#### Service layer

If you want to call anything a repository, this is where you would do it, but you used the name `ShopService`, so we'll keep that.

Since the state management layer above needed a reference to the service layer, you have to register that in GetIt as well:

```
void setUpGetIt() {
  // service layer
  getIt.registerLazySingleton<ShopService>(() => FakeShopService());

  // state management layer
  getIt.registerLazySingleton<ShopNotifier>(() => ShopNotifier());
}
```

Notice that I'm returning `FakeShopService`. That's useful during development so that you don't need to actually write the code to contact the server right away.

I'll define my abstract service class and fake implementation like so:

```dart
abstract class ShopService {
  Future<List<Shop>> getShopList();
}

class FakeShopService implements ShopService {
  @override
  Future<List<Shop>> getShopList() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    return [Shop(), Shop(), Shop()];
  }
}

class RealShopService implements ShopService {
  @override
  Future<List<Shop>> getShopList() async {
    // TODO: contact server and get JSON shop list
    // TODO: convert JSON to List<Shop>
  }
}
```

The fake implementation waits for three seconds (as in your example) to simulate connecting to a slow server. I don't know what your `Shop` data class looks like, so I just returned three empty shop classes that I defined simply like so:

```dart
class Shop {}
```

You can implement `RealShopService` whenever you want. When you do, all you need to do is switch it out in the GetIt registration like so:

```dart
void setUpGetIt() {
  // service layer
  getIt.registerLazySingleton<ShopService>(() => RealShopService());

  // ...
}
```

That's about it I think. Feel free to ask any follow up questions.

Comment: Thank you so much @Suragch. Initially I got confused as I tried to relate the layers of architecture with the one in Spring Boot(controller-service-repository). But, now I am crystal clear on each layer and how to use them. Thanks again for this wonderful explanation.

Comment: @DevAnand You're welcome. That's a good point about how a service and a repository could be distinguished. A repository is usually just a data source and in that case you would treat it the same as a service. However, a service could also be something else besides a repository. For example, an audio player service.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a valueNotifier for your listenable such as:

```
final shops = ValueNotifier<<List<Shops>>>(initialList);
```

Comment: Yes. But I have already used the instance of the class which extends ValueNotifier of List type. Do we still need to use ValueNotifier in service?

Comment: Yes, please check the following link, it is from the tutorial you are following. https://github.com/suragch/minimalist_state_management_timer_app/blob/master/lib/pages/timer_page/timer_page_logic.dart

Comment: I agree with you. They have used ValueNotifier for ButtonState like "final buttonNotifier = ValueNotifier<ButtonState>(ButtonState.initial);". But I am trying to implement a way how TimeLeftNotifier() is implemented in the same example, for which they have just "final timeLeftNotifier = TimeLeftNotifier();" (without ValueNotifier). This is because they extended the TimeLeftNotifier class with ValueNotifier. Please check the time_left_notifier.dart in notifiers folder in the same tutorial.